# Using onclick event with stream services into ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, geoevent-processor

I have one apartment lat-long.

With this I have 200 meters with some sensor data, and I have published web application with meter data.

I have used stream output with geoevent manager while observing the data only one marker is displayed.

Right now it is showing one real-time data into a single click.

Is it possible to configure with one field means with meter name can be seen with all data in one click?

Comment: If you add a TCP Output connector, and then fire up GeoEvent Logger, can you include 2-3 events that are being sent through.  This will help troubleshoot the issue.